# Using chernoff bounds for poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Chernoff inequality can be easily used for sum of independent Bernoulli distributions $X = X_1+X_2+...+X_n$:

> $P(X \geq (1+ \varepsilon)\mu) \leq e^{-\frac{\varepsilon^2\mu}{3}}$, where $\mu = EX$

How can we use it to estimate upper bound for
$P(Y \geq (1+ \varepsilon)\lambda)$, where Y is random variable with Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$?

Since it is all about estimations, as far as I understand, we can approximate Poisson distribution with binomial one, but still it is far from Bernoulli distribution which can be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large enough $n$, the Poisson distribution $\mathsf{Poisson}(\lambda)$ can be approximated as $\mathsf{Binomial}(n, \frac{\lambda}{n})$. Recall that a  random variable $X \sim \mathsf{Binomial}(n, \frac{\lambda}{n})$ can be represented as a sum of $n$ Bernoulli random variables; that is,
$$
X = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n
$$
where for $\forall 1 \leq i \leq n$,
$$
X_i =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{with probability } \frac{\lambda}{n} \\
0 & \text{with probability } 1 - \frac{\lambda}{n}
\end{cases}
$$
You can start from here and obtain an estimation.